# How to set the value of an enum type?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, freepascal, lazarus

I have the following:

```
TDirection = (dirNorth, dirEast, dirSouth, dirWest);
TDirections = set of TDirection;
```

In a seperate class I have it declared as a property:

```
property Directions: TDirections read FDirections write FDirections;
```

What I want is to be able to treat them as if they were Booleans, so for example if `dirNorth` was True then it would be `1`, if False it would be `0`.

I am trying to imagine it as `(1,0,0,0)`

I think to check if a direction is True, I could use:

```
var
  IsTrue: Boolean;
begin
  IsTrue := (DirNorth in Directions);
```

Not sure if the above is correct or not, but then my other problem is how to change one of the directions to `True` or `False`?

I have now reached one of my confusion states :(

This is the last thing I tried to set the value but I am getting Illegal Expression (in Lazarus).

```
Directions(TDirection(DirNorth)) := True;
```

Comment: Include(Directions, dirNorth); ?

Comment: and conversely, `Exclude(Directions, dirNorth);` to remove it again.

Comment: Read the documentation for sets

Comment: As Gerry Coll wrote in his comment of the answer bellow, include/exclude expect a set as var argument, hence you cannot pass a property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Directions` is a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) of elements of type `TDirection`.

To see if it [contains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Membership) `dirNorth`, do `dirNorth in Directions`. The result of using the `in` operator is a boolean; `dirNorth in Directions` is true iff the set `Directions` contains the element `dirNorth`.

To make sure `dirNorth` is included in `Directions`, do `Directions := Directions + [dirNorth]`.

To make sure `dirNorth` is *not* included in `Directions`, do `Directions := Directions - [dirNorth]`.

To set `Directions` to a particular value, simply assign: `Directions := [dirNorth, dirSouth]`.

Formally, `+` computes the [**union**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Unions) of two sets; `-` computes the [**set difference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Complements) of two sets. `*` computes the [**intersection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Intersections) of the two operands.

You also have the nice `Include` and `Exclude` functions: `Include(Directions, dirNorth)` does the same thing as `Directions := Directions + [dirNorth]`; `Exclude(Directions, dirNorth)` does the same thing as `Directions := Directions - [dirNorth]`.

For example, if

```
type
  TAnimal = (aDog, aCat, aRat, aRabbit);
  TAnimalSet = set of TAnimal;
const
  MyAnimals = [aDog, aRat, aRabbit];
  YourAnimals = [aDog, aCat];
```

then

```
aDog in MyAnimals = true;
aCat in MyAnimals = false;
aRat in YourAnimals = false;
aCat in YourAnimals = true;

MyAnimals + YourAnimals = [aDog, aRat, aRabbit, aCat];
MyAnimals - YourAnimals = [aRat, aRabbit];
MyAnimals * YourAnimals = [aDog];
```

Implicit in my answer is the fact that the Delphi `set` type is modelled after the mathematical [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29). For more information about the Delphi `set` type, please refer to [the official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Structured_Types#Sets).

Comment: Note that you can't use `Include` and `Exclude` on properties - it will give a `[DCC Error] XXXX.pas(200): E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to` error, you have to use `PropName + [element(s)`

Comment: This is all very helpful, but the first sentence should be "It's not possible to set the state of a set element directly without if/else" - because that was the question. This is really a missing feature, I think. As far as I understand it, the only improvement is writing a helper function, but it won't work with properties, just like Include/Exclude.

Answer (score 1):

You may add an item to a set by doing like this:

```
Include(Directions, dirNorth);
```

To remove it from the set:

```
Exclude(Diretions, dirNorth);
```

The help states that the result is the same as using the plus operator, but the code is more efficient.

Comment: As Gerry Coll wrote in his comment of the answer above, include/exclude expect a set as var argument, hence you cannot pass a property.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587876/1855801), which doesn't work for properties, I created this one (requires XE6) - it can be used for variables **and** properties:

```
TGridOptionsHelper = record helper for TGridOptions
public
  ///  <summary>Sets a set element based on a Boolean value</summary>
  ///  <example>
  ///    with MyGrid do Options:= Options.SetOption(goEditing, False);
  ///    MyVariable.SetOption(goEditing, True);
  ///  </example>
  function SetOption(GridOption: TGridOption; const Value: Boolean): TGridOptions;
end;

function TGridOptionsHelper.SetOption(
  GridOption: TGridOption; const Value: Boolean): TGridOptions;
begin
  if Value then Include(Self, GridOption) else Exclude(Self, GridOption);
  Result:= Self;
end;
```